# Why does SpaceX use Methane instead of Butane?

Tags: rockets

Genuinely, curious on why they use Methane as it's much harder to compress and liquefy whereas butane liquefies easily and is highly compressible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is butane never used in rockets as fuel?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48255/why-is-butane-never-used-in-rockets-as-fuel) (summary: it'd make more sense to use RP-1 than butane)

Comment: Additionally: SpaceX is planning to manufacture the fuel for return trip on Mars. Production of methane from CO2 is relatively simple and well understood. Production of butane is considerably harder.

Comment: @SF. that's an interesting enough notion that its worth adding as an answer, I'd say.

Comment: @SF, ...methane from CO2 _and water._ You can't make methane if you don't have hydrogen. https://www.space.com/future-astronauts-methane-rocket-fuel-mars.